# rails 3 update model from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model-view-controller

I have 3 tables: superhero, powers, teams

a superhero can have many powers and many teams.

for example:

```
superhero.rb
  name:string

  has_many :power_teams, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :powers, :through => :power_teams, :foreign_key => :power_id 
  has_many :teams, :through => :power_teams, :foreign_key => :team_id

power.rb
  name:string
  has_many :power_teams, :dependent => :destroy

team.rb
  name:string
  has_many :power_teams, :dependent => :destroy

#This is what I want to add to
power_team
  belongs_to :superhero
  belongs_to :power
  belongs_to :team
```

UPDATE here's the controller for superhero

```
def create
  @hero = Superhero.new(params[:hero])
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@hero) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  #Teams are a drop-down, you can only choose 1 team
  <%= f.collection_select(:team_ids, Team.all(:order=>:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>

  #powers are checkboxes, you can choose multiple powers
  <% Power.all.each do |power| %>
     <label class="checkbox">
     <%= check_box_tag "superhero[power_ids][]", power.id, @hero.power_ids.include?(power.id) %>
     <%= power.name %>
     </label>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I save, 1 team and 2 powers I get this (in the index page):

```
Hero | Power | Team
  1      1     
  1      2
  1              1
```

Is this right? I thought I would be seeing and expecting this:

```
Hero | Power | Team
  1      1       1
  1      2       1
```

Comment: Odds are low that you need to use an after_save hook as you mentioned just to set the association. This seems wrong: `@power_team = PowerTeam.new(params[:power_ids][:team_ids])` as it would be assuming that the request parameter `power_id` will be accessible using the key `:power_ids` and will return a hash with a key,  `:team_ids`, which almost certainly isn't the case. Also, without the schema or form code, etc. you are using, it requires a number of assumptions and guesswork to assist, so it might help to add that info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to create a relationship between powers and teams, and power_team currently only has an association declared for power. If you have team_id on the power_teams table, then you should probably have this in the power_team model also:

```
belongs_to :team
```

That might not be the only problem. It's difficult to tell since you defined the models only partially, didn't define your schema, and didn't provide the code for the form, etc. that you were using to try to update.

Be sure that you have associations set up both ways in each model and that definition of the association matches. Use a belongs_to if it has a foreign key column in the model's table, or a has_one/has_many (depending on how many records you expect to return) if it is the associated model's table that has the foreign key column defined for this model, or has_and_belongs_to_many (a.k.a. "HABTM") if you have a join table that *only* has two columns- one for each foreign key to the two tables it is joining. It looks like you've already done the dependent destroy for a few, so no need to mention that. If you were integrating with a legacy schema then if you were using a non-standard table name on either side of the association, non-standard join table name, non-standard foreign key column names and/or ids, or non-standard model class name, then you would need to set the other options of the association correctly for both sides of the association.

Even though you noted in a comment that mass assignment security is not a problem, be sure that if you expect to update associated objects (and assuming you are using Rails 3.1+ with mass assignment security and whitelisting as is the default in latest 3.2.x) that you are adding `_attributes` to the end of the attribute name defined in `attr_accessible` for things you are accepting nested attributes for. In Rails 4, mass assignment security is going away, so if you have any interest in using strong_parameters, this would be a good time to look into that and other new Rails 4 technologies (rails-api, ActiveModel::Serializers, etc.) which can be used currently in Rails 3.

*Update:*

Since question was updated, I see now that superhero has an association to power_teams and vice versa. That association is not necessary in either superhero or power_team, so I'd remove it. There still seems to be some missing code from the controller in the question, as it should be routing to the "new" action method when the create form is loaded, and to the "create" action method for accepting the form submit, so there should be at least two methods called "new" and "create". It may be a good idea to start a new project and use the rails generate scaffold method to get the initial stuff now that you have the schema straight (with the change I just mentioned in this to remove the superhero association to power_team and vice versa). I know you are not new to Rails based on other questions, but it is always good just to see the baseline as an example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I've tried this, but I don't think it has to do with Mass assignment security, I'm trying to update a seperate relationship model. I have the model superhero that updates the nested relationship for teams and powers (superhero_team, superhero_power), what I want to do is from that same query update a relationship table between power and team (power_team). The problem is that superhero has no relationship to the (power_team) table

Comment: Updated the answer to indicate that I assume you'd want to use a `belongs_to :team` on power_team model, although it is tough to tell, since I don't know what the schema looks like. Hope that helps.

Comment: @gary-s-weaver Thanks for the comments, I've changed the relationship models around, I dropped the superhero_team and power_superheros and create a power_superhero_team team table with 3 belongs_to, I kind of have it working. The problem is I get this saved: (picture this as a table (heading)superhero team power (line 1)[1,1,blank](line 2)[1,blank,2]. What I want is [1,1,2].

Comment: @jmorrissette No problem. Please update the question to indicate your current code in the controller you are hitting with the form, the models related to the problem, and the form to help figure it out more quickly. It just sounds like it is doing two creates, but not sure why without seeing it.

Comment: @gary-s-weaver I've modified the question, I can see what you mean by two creates, it seems to creating once for powers then once for teams (two creates), I would like it to create just once, feel like I need an "each" somewhere in there?